# Godot engine collision with KinematicBody doesn't work

Tags: collision, godot, gdscript

I was fiddling around with the Godot engine and tried a little game.

But I can't seem to get an info on colliding.

```
if is_colliding():
    print ("Collision with " + get_collider())
    get_node("Sprite").set_texture(walk_cycle_right_1)
    move_state_right = 1
    set_pos(Vector2(get_pos().x -10, get_pos().y))
```

It always prints `false`. I'm moving my character (`KinematicBody2d` -> `Sprite/CollisionShape2d`) with the `set_pos` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the kinematicbody you need to use move or move_to to trigger the collision.
If you really need to use set_pos, check collisionshape2d.shape and do the collision check yourself.

There is an example on Godot documentation where KinematicBody2D movement and collisiong handling is introduced: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/kinematic_character_2d.html

Full definition for KinematicBody2D class is available also at Godot Documentation:
http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html?highlight=KinematicBody2D

Comment: Ok. Thank you ;-)

Comment: I used set_pos to make the Blaster go in 360 Directions. But how can I achieve this   with move()?

Comment: @Linuxer4Fun You should accept the answer and ask another question. Do not ask different questions in comments.

Comment: @sm4 ok. Sorry.